# How to shutdown glog completely to run go tests?

Tags: go, glog

I'm writing test code for my code and would like to get 100% code coverage.

This implies testing corner cases that calls `glog.Fatal()` for instance.

So first thing I need is to disable any output by glog because I'm not testing glog. So I can run go test without generating files in `/tmp` or spittig messages to `stderr`.

The second thing I need is that a call to `glog.Fatal()` which calls `os.Exit()` doesn't interfere with running the test.

How could I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it by programming to the `glog` interface.  I'm not sure what that is but it could look like

```
type Logger interface {
  Fatal()
  Info()
  // etc...
}
```

Then your packages/functions/structs etc, would have to require the interface opposed to including a global.

```
type SomeStruct struct {
  log Logger
}
```

Or on your top level modules:

```
func SomeFunc(log Logger) {}
```

Using an interface decouples your code from a loggers specific implementation.

In your unit tests you can create a test specific logger, which is a stub, or a mock.

```
type TestLogger struct {}
func (tl TestLogger) Fatal() {}
func (tl TestLogger) Info() {}
// etc....
```

Then your code has to be able to instantiate and configure the real `Glog` instance, in your production code.  To test this, it should be as simple as encapsulating "creating" a Glog instance.

```
func NewLogger Logger {
  // configure `Glog` 
  // return `Glog`
}
```

This way you should be able to unit test the `NewLogger` configures a logger correctly without actually having to make calls to the logger.

Comment: That looks interesting. I'll remove glog dependencies. It uses a global.